# Custom attribute (read-only) in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, laravel-5.1, accessor

I have Cam model and for each cam I have a folder with images on server. I just need to get all image names in custom attribute but I don't get it. There is no need to call actions within table. I tried extending constructor but no luck.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cam extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cams';
    protected $guarded = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $images = null;

    public function __construct($attributes = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);

        $this->images = 'kk';
    }

    public function getVideosAttribute($value) {
        return explode(',', $value);
    }

    public function city() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
    }
}
```

Comment: And where in this code you are getting image files from server. I see here you are using `$this->images = 'kk'` in constructor - what for?

Comment: It's just for testing purpose. I'll handle that later that's not problem!

Comment: how are you attempting to read files in a folder ?

Comment: Why is that important? Every cam has folder named by it's id. Inside it are stored images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for something like this (I assume your `$images` variable is just for testing and it's not a column in your table in database).

You can add to your `Cam` model:

```
protected $images= null;
```

and now your new method:

```
public function getImagesAttribute($value) {
    if ($this->images === null) {
       $this->images = glob(storage_path('cams/'.$this->id.'/*'));
    }
    return $this->images;
}
```

And now for each Cam you can use:

```
dd($cam->images)
```

to get list of images for selected Cam

In above code I assume your cam images are in in `storage/cams/{$cam_id}/` path and you have in that folder only pictures

And now you can get cams and display images for them using for example this code:

```
$cams = Cams::all(); 
foreach ($cams as $cam) 
{
    echo implode("\n", $cam->images); 
}
```

Of course if you have thousands of files you should probably store file names in database because it might be more effective than scanning your disk each time to get images but everything depends on your application usage.

Comment: And by using this accessor laravel won't try to do anything with images in the database?

Comment: Yeah I get it. Also, should if ($images === null) be if ($this->images === null). btw $value param doesn't have any function it's just for preventing errors?

Comment: @Covik No it won't, you are right, I fixed it, please look at sample code to get cam images in my edited answer